# Find the last index of getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

This script will change the second paragraph to "Hello World!"

But if I add a 3rd paragraph how would i have it automatically change the 3rd paragraph instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to change the text of this paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It changed the THIRD paragraph since JS arrays and collections stat at 0. Updated to do what you said it does

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName tells you that getElementsByTagName returns an HTMLCollection, and if you follow the link to that, you'll see that it has a `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

`p:last-of-type` works well for this:

[:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("p:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to change the text of this paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't change the second paragraph but the third instead. You can store all paragraphs into an array and simply choose the last one like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change the text of this paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  ps[ps.length -1].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the little bit code to get last paragraph tag

```js
function myFunction() {
    //it will return the array of paragraph tags
    let pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    //to get last paragraph simple minus one the length of array
    pTags[pTags.length - 1].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to change the text of this paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is also a paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```